# Take photo in camera and edit it

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I need take a photo and edit it.
I used origin camera and return big size image, so when I try create new template image to edit, the application will be forse close because outOfMemoryError.
is there any way help me resize image before load it into my application?

My code take image in camera:

```
void loadImageFromCamera(){
    Intent takePicture = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = null;
    try{
        // place where to store camera taken picture
        photo = this.createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
        photo.delete();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
}
private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception{
    File tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    tempDir = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/.temp/");
    if(!tempDir.exists()){
        tempDir.mkdir();
    }
    return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
}
public void grabImage(){
    this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageUri, null);
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    try {
        originImage = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mImageUri);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

}
```